# Running R Markdown from R

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm completely new to this, and follow instructions on wiki to run some `R` and `R markdown` code. But I continue to receive errors.

In VisualStudio I have `Script.R` file:

```
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
library(scales)
Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC = "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc")

rmarkdown::render("test_results.rmd", output_format = "html_document", 
        output_file = "test_results_data_417.html",
        params = list(filename = "input_file_template.xlsx",
                    connection_string = "driver={SQL Server};server=ServerName;database=DBName;trusted_connection=true"
                    ))
```

When I run above script, I receive following error:
[image]

Can you please lead me through this process? I can attach anything else that is required. Thanks

*EDIT*

Here is script `testing.R`, to where error refers:

```
library(RODBC)
library(readxl)


load_file <- function(query_filename) {

    query_file <- read_excel(query_filename, col_types = c("text", "text", "text"))

    query_file$control_query <- as.character(gsub("[\r\n]", " ", query_file$control_query))
    query_file$test_query <- as.character(gsub("[\r\n]", " ", query_file$test_query))

    query_file
}

run_tests <- function(connection_string, query_filename) {

    query_file <- read_excel(query_filename,col_types = c("text", "text", "text"))

    query_file$control_query <- as.character(gsub("[\r\n]", " ", query_file$control_query))
    query_file$test_query <- as.character(gsub("[\r\n]", " ", query_file$test_query))

    dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect(connection_string)

    all_results <- data.frame(  test_name = character(),
                                control_query = character(),
                                test_query = character(),
                                control_results = character(),
                                test_results = character(),
                                passed = character(),
                                stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                             )

    for (i in 1:NROW(query_file)) {

        test_name <- query_file[[i, "test"]]
        control_query <- query_file[[i, "control_query"]]
        test_query <- query_file[[i, "test_query"]]

        control_results <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, control_query)
        test_results <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, test_query)
        passed <- control_results == test_results

        new_row <- as.data.frame( c(test_name, control_query, test_query, control_results, test_results, passed))
        names(new_row) <- c("test_name", "control_query", "test_query", "control_results", "test_results", "passed")
        all_results <- rbind(all_results, new_row)

    }
    odbcClose(dbhandle)
    all_results
}
```

Here is `test_results.rmd` Basically, this must be a flow Script.R->test_results.rmd->testing.R

````
---
output: html_document
css: rmd_style.css
params: 
   filename: None
   connection_string: None
title: "Test Results For `r params$filename`"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE , warning = FALSE, include = FALSE}
library(RODBC)
library(readxl)
library(knitr)
library(scales)

source(".\\testing.R")

test_results <- run_tests(params$connection_string, params$filename)
names(test_results) <- c("Test Name", "Control Query", "Test Query", "Control Results", "Test Results", "Passed")
```

<br><br>



```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
kable(test_results, format.args = list(digits = 10, nsmall = 0, decimal.mark = ".", big.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE))
```
````

Comment: Are you able to successfully run the R statements outside a markdown job? The error message indicates that there is a problem in lines 12 - 21 of the R code in your markdown file, where you try to set 6 names as attributes to a vector that has only one element.

Comment: @LenGreski , sorry if question is weird, how I can run script.R without markdown, if markdown is basically the only thing I run in script.R. I see lines 12-21. Updating post

Comment: I'm not familiar with running R in VisualStudio, but with RStudio I can run each code chunk in an R Markdown file interactively and verify that the R code is working before I knit to HTML or PDF.

Comment: @LenGreski can you do that test, running each code chunk, in a fresh R session?

Comment: @Gregor -- not to be inscrutably logical, but what do you mean by a "fresh R session?"

Comment: Restart R, run the code in your chunks without running anything else first. (Though really you should set the working directory to the directory that `test_results.rmd` is in).

Comment: @Gregor - thanks. As I noted in my earlier comment, "with RStudio..." yes, I can start RStudio, load the Rmd file, and execute code chunks interactively from the Rmd file by using the `Run Selected Lines` menu item from the pulldown menu list in the code editor window.

Comment: Can you render a simple example document from Visual Studio? Try the default document that is produced when you open a new Rmd document in RStudio.

Comment: And I'm confused what `testing.R` script has to do with anything.  The script you are trying to render is called `test_results.rmd`, and the error message calls out that document. `testing.R` does not appear to be an Rmarkdown script...

Comment: @Gregor, I've added to post test_results.rmd , those are all files, there is also css file, which shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @LenGreski , I've added to post test_results.rmd , those are all files, there is also css file, which shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @Gregor, testing.R runs without any problem, all files are in same directory

Comment: @Sher - Unless testing.R has a compile error, it will run without error because neither function is executed. To test this outside the markdown file you'll need to load the libraries and run `source(.\\testing.R);test_results <- run_tests(params$connection_string, params$filename);
names(test_results) <- c("Test Name", "Control Query", "Test Query", "Control Results", "Test Results", "Passed")` in R, preferably through an interactive debugger so you can step thru the code to figure out which query results in only one item in the `new_row <- as.data.frame(...)` line.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your efforts. Post below worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the error does not come from R-Markdown but that there is a syntax error in the following lines:

```
new_row <- as.data.frame( c(test_name, control_query, test_query, control_results, test_results, passed))
names(new_row) <- c("test_name", "control_query", "test_query", "control_results", "test_results", "passed")
```

As far as I can see, the variables `test_name`, `control_query`, etc, are constants, so when you call `as.data.frame()` on them inside the concatenate function `c()`, you actually create a data frame with **one** column instead of **six**, as you pass it one vector.

The error now arises when you try to change the names attribute of the data frame `new_row`. `names(new_row)` returns a vector containing the column names and has length one in your case. You try to overwrite that with a vector of length six.

Replacing the two lines with the following code should solve the issue:

```
# Using data.frame to convert variables into data frame

new_row <- data.frame( test_name, control_query, test_query, control_results, test_results, passed)
```

In this case, you don't even need to change the names attribute anymore. `data.frame()` automatically uses the variable names as column names.

Hope that helps.
Cheers